# Redcarpet Markdown gem: instantiating the Markdown object only once & reusing it between parses

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, markdown, redcarpet

I was reading through Redcarpet's [documentation](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet) and came across this sentence:

```
The Markdown object is encouraged to be instantiated once with the required settings, and reused between parses.
```

What is the best way to go about doing this in a `Rails` app?

I watched Ryan Bates' railscast on Redcarpet and he has a helper method in `application_helper.rb` where every method call instantiates a new `Redcarpet` object, like so:

```
def markdown(text)
  options = [:hard_wrap, :filter_html, :autolink, :no_intraemphasis, :fenced_code, :gh_blockcode]
  Redcarpet.new(text, *options).to_html.html_safe
end
```

Is this not the best way to go about doing this? Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the *rails* way of doing things, but it seems fine, and doesn't violate POLA or the like, so hopefully it will suit your needs.

Create a `markdown.rb` file in your `config/initializers/` folder, and use some variation of the following code snippet:

```
class MultiRenderer < Redcarpet::Render::HTML
  include Redcarpet::Render::SmartyPants
end

module Paradox
  Markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(MultiRenderer)
end
```

Replace `Paradox` with the name of your application. You can add various options to the renderer or the instance of markdown, as described in the [readme](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet). The renderer I created (the `MultiRenderer`) has built in smartypants, so you can round quotes and whatnot

To use Markdown, simply call `YourApp::Markdown.render(text)`, and you'll get html back. You probably need to run html_safe on that.

Comment: Is this global renderer thread safe? Very important when using multi-threaded environments like Puma or Sidekiq.

Comment: can anyone please confirm if it is thread safe to use redcarpet object between multiple threads. eg: with thin or puma??

Comment: I tested it with a simple script, using concurrent-ruby and latches, and it does appear to be threadsafe, since rendering markdown doesn't affect the markdown renderer (you can test that by freezing your markdown object)